# How to reduce the load from Disk by improving my.ini settings for MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, my.cnf

I have created a time tracking app which captures every minute activity of 400 people.

Means if no one query my database I still have 400 insert request to MySQL every minute.

Everything working fine till now but then I have to give the user a dashboard where they can see every entry of their tracked time.

Now I have 400 people querying my database, after launching query page the system becomes very slow, Disk usage go to 100% much time. I'm planning to deploy more apps on the server but before moving forward I want to solve this problem.

I'm thinking of changing my hard disk from HHD to SSD to increase read-write speed but wondering If there are any settings I can tweak in my default my.ini file to get better MySQL performance

Below is the `my.ini` file I have modified with the help of `my-innodb-heavy-4G.ini` my PC running MySQL 10.1.36-MariaDB,64bit, 3.60GHz, i7 with 8 GB RAM.

I just wanted to know if the below settings are correct or not. I don't want my server to crash and stop working. Please help me in addition or deletion of any setting line which can cause an issue.

```
[client] 
# password       = your_password 
port            = 3306 
socket          = "E:/xampp2/mysql/mysql.sock"


# Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket = "E:/xampp2/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "E:/xampp2/mysql" 
tmpdir = "E:/xampp2/tmp" 
datadir = "E:/xampp2/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer_size = 32M
max_allowed_packet = 16M

#
back_log = 50
slow_query_log
long_query_time = 8

#
table_open_cache = 2048
binlog_cache_size = 5M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
join_buffer_size = 8M
tmp_table_size = 64M

sort_buffer_size = 8M
net_buffer_length = 8M
read_buffer_size = 8M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 32M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 64M
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 10G
myisam_repair_threads = 1
myisam_recover

#
thread_cache_size = 8M
query_cache_size = 64M
query_cache_limit = 2M
thread_concurrency = 8M
thread_stack = 240K

max_connections = 5000
log_error = "mysql_error.log"


plugin_dir = "E:/xampp2/mysql/lib/plugin/" 

server-id   = 1


innodb_data_home_dir = "E:/xampp2/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "E:/xampp2/mysql/data"


innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 200M

innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120
innodb_write_io_threads = 8
innodb_read_io_threads = 8
innodb_thread_concurrency = 16
innodb_log_files_in_group = 3
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90


[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash



[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 512M
sort_buffer_size = 512M
read_buffer = 8M
write_buffer = 8M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Comment: Sounds like a simple indexing problem.  But we need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, the query, and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  (Wilson's request may find other issues to fix.)  And, how big is the table?

Comment: @YatendraRanawat Since it is about 9 months later and you have not posted anything requested on Apr 3, 2019, you no longer would like any assistance with your question.  Please indicate anything you would like for us to consider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```py
# Example MySQL config file for small systems. 
# 
# This is for a system with little memory (<= 64M) where MySQL is only used 
# from time to time and it's important that the mysqld daemon 
# doesn't use much resources. 
# 
# You can copy this file to 
# E:/xampp2/mysql/bin/my.cnf to set global options, 
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this 
# installation this directory is E:/xampp2/mysql/data) or 
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options. 
# 
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports. 
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program 
# with the "--help" option. 
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients 

[client]

# password       = your_password 
port            = 3306 
socket          = "E:/xampp2/mysql/mysql.sock" 
# Here follows entries for some specific programs 
# The MySQL server 

[mysqld]
port= 3306 
socket = "E:/xampp2/mysql/mysql.sock" 
basedir = "E:/xampp2/mysql" 
tmpdir = "E:/xampp2/tmp" 
datadir = "E:/xampp2/mysql/data" 
pid_file = "mysql.pid" 
# enable-named-pipe 
key_buffer_size = 32M 
max_allowed_packet = 16M 
# back_log = 50
slow_query_log 
long_query_time = 8 
# table_open_cache = 2048 
binlog_cache_size = 5M 
max_heap_table_size = 64M 
join_buffer_size = 8M 
tmp_table_size = 64M 
sort_buffer_size = 8M 
net_buffer_length = 8M 
read_buffer_size = 8M 
read_rnd_buffer_size = 32M 
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M 
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 64M 
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 10G 
myisam_repair_threads = 1 myisam_recover 
# thread_cache_size = 8M 
query_cache_size = 64M 
query_cache_limit = 2M 
thread_concurrency = 8M 
thread_stack = 240K 
max_connections = 5000 
log_error = "mysql_error.log" 
# Change here for bind listening 
# bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6 

# Where do all the plugins live 
plugin_dir = "E:/xampp2/mysql/lib/plugin/" 
# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement, 
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host. 
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes. 
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows 
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless! 
# 
# commented in by lampp security 
#skip-networking 
#skip-federated 
# Replication Master Server (default) 
# binary logging is required for replication 
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11 
#log-bin=mysql-bin 
# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1 
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set 
# but will not function as a master if omitted server-id    = 1 
# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this) 
# 
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between 
# two methods : 
# 
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) - 
#    the syntax is: 
# 
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>, 
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ; 
# 
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and 
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default). 
# 
#    Example: 
# 
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306, 
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret'; 
# 
# OR 
# 
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then 
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example 
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to 
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later 
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and 
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown 
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server. 
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched 
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above) 
# 
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1 
# (and different from the master) 
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set 
# but will not function as a slave if omitted 
#server-id       = 2 
# 
# The replication master for this slave - required 
#master-host     =   <hostname> 
# 
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting 
# to the master - required 
#master-user     =   <username> 
# 
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to 
# the master - required 
#master-password =   <password> 
# 
# The port the master is listening on. 
# optional - defaults to 3306 
#master-port     =  <port> 
# 
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended 
#log-bin=mysql-bin 
# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks 
#
tmpdir = "E:/xampp2/tmp" 
#log-update = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname 
# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables 
#bdb_cache_size = 40M 
#bdb_max_lock = 10000 
# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables 
#skip-innodb 
innodb_data_home_dir = "E:/xampp2/mysql/data" 
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend 
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "E:/xampp2/mysql/data" 
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "E:/xampp2/mysql/data" 
#
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 % 
#
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high 
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G 
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 200M 
#
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size 
innodb_log_file_size = 256M 
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M 
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1 
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120 
innodb_write_io_threads = 8 
innodb_read_io_threads = 8 
innodb_thread_concurrency = 16 
innodb_log_files_in_group = 3 
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90 
#
# UTF 8 Settings 
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\' 
#collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci 
#character_set_server=utf8 
#skip-character-set-client-handshake 
#character_sets-dir="E:/xampp2/mysql/share/charsets" 

[mysqldump]
quick 
max_allowed_packet = 16M 

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash 
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL 
#safe-updates 

[myisamchk]

key_buffer_size = 512M 
sort_buffer_size = 512M 
read_buffer = 8M 
write_buffer = 8M 

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Comment: What is "this"? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it